# Need to trigger text scroll with start of audio file

Tags: html, events, audio, scroll, triggers

Currently I have different audio files displayed using tables in html5 and css. In each cell with the audio file is text which has artist information etc. What I want to happen is the text to scroll within the cell only when that particular audio file is playing. Right now I can make the text scroll using the marquee feature but I can't figure out how to make it only scroll when only that audio file is playing.

Comment: Can you post associated code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: <td><center><img src="images/artists/Becca.png"width="110" heigth="110"><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">Becca - Trap (J Paul Mix)</marquee><audio controls>
        <source src="mp3s/TrapJPaulMix.m4a" type="audio/mp3">
        <source src="mp3s/TrapJPaulMix.ogg">
        <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio. Here is a<a href="mp3s/TrapJPaulMix.m4a">link to the audio</a>instead.</p></audio></center></td>

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding so I'm honestly lost.

Answer (score 0):

Note: That `marquee` is deprecated...

But to solve this specific problem if it's going to be executed in a supported browsers

See snippet

```js
marq = document.getElementById("marq");;
marq.style.opacity = "0";
aud = document.getElementById("aud");;
aud.onplay = function() {
  marq.style.display = "auto";
  marq.start();
  marq.style.opacity = "1";
}
aud.onpause = function() {
  marq.stop();
}
```

```html
<td>
  <center>
    <img src="images/artists/Becca.png" width="110" heigth="110">
    <marquee id="marq" behavior="" direction="left">Becca - Trap (J Paul Mix)</marquee>
    <audio controls id="aud">
      <source src="http://mp3-pesni.org/music/3dc9ed0908d29016e2d41e8abb0a31fd.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio. Here is a<a href="mp3s/TrapJPaulMix.m4a">link to the audio</a>instead.</p>
    </audio>
  </center>
</td>
```

---

**Nevertheless, I advise that you use css3 animation to mimic that `marquee` tag**

See snippet below

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title");

aud = document.getElementById("aud");;
aud.onplay = function() {
  title.classList.remove('stop');
  title.classList.add('running');
}
aud.onpause = function() {
  title.classList.remove('running');
  title.classList.add('stop');
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes anime {
  0% {
    right: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    right: -100%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes anime {
  0% {
    right: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    right: -100%;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes anime {
  0% {
    right: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    right: -100%;
  }
}
@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    right: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    right: -100%;
  }
}
#marq {
  border: solid black 1px;
  ;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
}
#title {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: anime;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  color: green;
}
.stop {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.running {
  animation-play-state: running;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <center>
    <img src="images/artists/Becca.png" width="110" heigth="110">
    <div id="marq">
      <div id="title">
        Song 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <audio controls id="aud">
      <source src="http://mp3-pesni.org/music/3dc9ed0908d29016e2d41e8abb0a31fd.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio. Here is a<a href="mp3s/TrapJPaulMix.m4a">link to the audio</a>instead.</p>
    </audio>
  </center>
</td>
```

Comment: Please don't recommend using `marquee`. It is considered obsolete and was first deprecated in 2013.

Comment: I know..I was going to put that in this answer but it seems that the OP is ineterested in this...I will edited answer to make a note of this....

Comment: Thank you for that. Since Marquee is no longer used what is the goto code for this type of thing nowadays? Thanks

Comment: @JonStevens note too that animations are only supported in modern browsers....check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp